# Dynamic resizing today widget

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.3, today-extension

I implemented an table view into my today widget. The tableView has no fixed number of cells. Because of this the height of the widget has to change dynamically. Does someone knows how I can find out the height of the tableView? If I know the height of the tableView I can use the same height for the today widget. Or is there a better solution?

My code:

```
var preferredViewHeight:CGFloat{return 132}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  self.tableView.reloadData()
  updateSize()
}

func updateSize() {

  var preferredSize = self.preferredContentSize
  preferredSize.height = self.preferredViewHeight
  self.preferredContentSize = preferredSize
}

func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)!) {

  self.tableView.reloadData()
  completionHandler(NCUpdateResult.NewData)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to compute the total height of the table? you can achieve that by using `tableView.contentSize`

Comment: It works. If you post it as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can achieve that by using `tableView.contentSize` this will tell you the total size of the tables content.

Comment: Can you please give more details on how to use `tableView.contenSize` ?

Answer (score 1):

As answered above, you would implement it as:

```
func widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange(_ activeDisplayMode: NCWidgetDisplayMode, withMaximumSize maxSize: CGSize) {
    switch activeDisplayMode {
    case .compact:
        preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: maxSize.width, height: 300)
    case .expanded:
        preferredContentSize = tableView.contentSize
    }
}
```